# Using Typescript with Breezejs

Tags: typescript, breeze

I am trying to use BreezeJS with the standard Typescript type definition files.  Using the test file as a guide, I have the following:

```
/// <reference path="../typings/breeze/breeze.d.ts" />

import breeze = module(Breeze);

class ExerciseEntityManager {
    manager: breeze.EntityManager;

    constructor() {
        this.manager = new breeze.EntityManager({
            serviceName: 'api/ExerciseItems'
        });
    }

    GetAllExercises(success: any, fail?: any) {
        var query = Breeze.EntityQuery.from('ExerciseItems');

        // TODO: Make sure this works if fail is undefined
        return this.manager.executeQuery(query)
            .then(success)
            .fail(fail);
    }
}
```

This compiles to the following:

```
var breeze = Breeze;
var ExerciseEntityManager = (function () {
    function ExerciseEntityManager() {
        this.manager = new breeze.EntityManager({
            serviceName: 'api/ExerciseItems'
        });
    }
    ExerciseEntityManager.prototype.GetAllExercises = function (success, fail) {
        var query = Breeze.EntityQuery.from('ExerciseItems');
        return this.manager.executeQuery(query).then(success).fail(fail);
    };
    return ExerciseEntityManager;
})();
```

When I load this into my page, I get the javascript error: 'Uncaught reference error: Breeze is not defined.'  I get a similar error using the breeze-tests.ts file from the breeze repository, so I am obviously doing something wrong.

If I comment out the 'var breeze = Breeze;' line from the compiled file, it works, but this is obviously not an ideal solution.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Breeze typescript definition files were updated in v 1.2.5 and I don't see the error in that build.  Can you try 1.2.5 and repost as to whether that was the issue?